# Glyphicons showing up as squares (bootstrap 3.2.0)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, glyphicons

I am trying to load search glyphicon with the following:

```html
<div tabindex="6" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">...<.div>
```

But, glyphicon loading as the following:

[image]

What is the solution?

```css
background-color:none transparent}@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);src:url(/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),url(/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),url(/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular)
```

Comment: Watch your browser developer tools console, in 99% of issues like this the answer is within errors/warnings there.

Comment: no error or warning!

Comment: I found that search is not at all loaded. It has - only - .glyphicon {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; and .glyphicon-search:before {
content: "\e003";

Comment: Please add bootstap CSS to head of your html file <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 0):

Check this  code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div tabindex="6">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 3.3.5 is not my requirement. It works fine there. 3.2.0 is the issue and I think fonts folder is the issue. Its in my grunt task may be

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Bootstrap3.2.0](https://app.box.com/s/8v0xgbliy5y2m3c38f5gaei0ytlsbidx) downloaded from [Bootstrap site](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/getting-started/)

Unpack and run below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div tabindex="6">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Worked as like as BS3.5

Answer (score 0):

Though a late answer, for someone who has this issue:

Using Bootstrap's CDN in the  tag solved this issue for me.